# Importing a set of X-Y coordinates - data gets split and partly misplaced at the boundary of Austria GK Central and Austria GK East

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, austria

I have an Excel file of coordinates of a line structure (think river or infrastructure like road, railways etc) without any info about the coordinate system except that it says `GK` in the X and Y headers in Excel.

And QGIS automatically picked `EPSG:31255 - MGI / Austria GK Central` when I imported the CSV I made from the Excel and this fits for most of the data (all features exactly fit to the basemap aerial picture), except for the features that are east of the `Austria GK Central` area. Instead of continuing towards the east, they end up in the far west (in Tirol, so in the `EPSG:31254 Austria GK West` zone).

[image: sketch of the issue]

(sketch of the issue, I can't show the original, proprietary data)

I can "fix" it with an easy workaround: simply split the file into two, an *east* file, with the data that wrongly ends up in the west, imported with the `Austria GK east` zone, and a *central* file, with the correctly imported data. While this works, that doesn't really seem like the proper solution.

Comment: The proper solution, if you want one dataset, is to use a coordinate system that covers the entire map extent *after* splitting out the data in two different reference systems, then reproject each and append them.